# E-mail address verify status

Tags: django, django-allauth

I wanna check user's e-mail verify status for displaying a warning message. If e-mail address is not verified, i will show a message top of the page.

Is there any template tag for checking user's e-mail address is confirmed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a verification field in the user model? Post some of your code for review.

Comment: Am using django-allauth @TimS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/), to verify the same as shown below:

**app_tags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def verify_email(email):
    ...
    if email_verified:
        return True
    else
        return False
```

**example.html**

```
{% load app_tags %}
...
{% verify_email email as email_verified %}
{% if email_verified %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but am using django-allauth. Verification is a module in this package.